# Trying to turn a .txt file into a dictionary of words. Where am I going wrong? (C#)

Tags: c#, dictionary, console-application

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/temp/TextFile.txt").Select(x => x.Split('/')).FirstOrDefault();
            var words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                words.Add(lines[i], lines[i + 1]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(words);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it this appears:"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this code or if you know of an better way of doing what I am trying to do.

-Thanks

Comment: `Dictionary<>` doesn't define `ToString()`.  If you want to print the contents, you need to write code that does that.

Comment: Show us some example lines of `C:/temp/TextFile.txt`, and what you want to print out.

Comment: You do realize that the `FirstOrDefault` will result in just processing the first line of the file, right?  Maybe you want `SelectMany` instead of `Select`?

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.Select(kvp=>kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var words = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/temp/TextFile.txt")
                .Select(x => x.Split('/'))
                .Where(x => x.Length == 2)
                .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

It reads the file, and splits it as you currently do. The where simply checks that it's a pair and there aren't more/less elements (to prevent an exception in case of the latter). Finally, it converts it to a dictionary.

I'm not sure what you want to do with regards to writing it out. juharr's suggestion in the comments should work:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.Select(kvp=>kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value)));
```

or you can loop through each pair:

```
foreach (var pair in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ":" + pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all well except for trying to print a whole dictionary in one line of code.

Instead you could print the word as you add it to the dictionary, or you could do a foreach loop on the dictionary object to print each Key-Value-Pair, or you could write a Helper/Extension method to handle WriteLine on a Dictionary.

Here scenario 1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/temp/TextFile.txt").Select(x => x.Split('/')).FirstOrDefault();
            var words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                words.Add(lines[i], lines[i + 1]);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", lines[i], lines[i + 1]));
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(words);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Scenario 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/temp/TextFile.txt").Select(x => x.Split('/')).FirstOrDefault();
            var words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                words.Add(lines[i], lines[i + 1]);
            }

            foreach (var kvp in words)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Scenario 3:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/temp/TextFile.txt").Select(x => x.Split('/')).FirstOrDefault();
            var words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                words.Add(lines[i], lines[i + 1]);
            }

            PrintDictionary(words);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

       static void PrintDictionary(Dictionary<string,string> dict)
       {
           foreach (var kvp in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            }
       }
    }
}
```